# Activate hyphenation formatting while generating Excel document with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter, libreoffice-calc

[image]

I'm using Python to generate an excel document from a Pandas DataFrame.

I can set column width and text wrap with `workbook.add_format({"text_wrap": True})` and `worksheet.set_column(f"{cols[idx]}:{cols[idx]}", 30, format)`, but I don't know how to activate "Hyphenation active". I fail to find it in the doc : [https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format)

Here is a sample of my code :

```
df = get_pandas_dataframe()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine="xlsxwriter")
sheet_name = "abc"
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
max_row, max_col = pdf.shape
format = workbook.add_format({"text_wrap": True})
cols = dict(zip(range(26), list(string.ascii_uppercase)))
for idx, col in enumerate(df):
    worksheet.set_column(f"{cols[idx]}:{cols[idx]}", 30, format)
writer.save()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hyphenation Active" isn't an Excel option and hence it isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

You can verify that yourself in Libreoffice by saving an xlsx file with that option in a cell, closing the file, and then re-opening it. The option will no longer be there.

Comment: Oh... too bad :( Thank you anyway